# Кисть рисует лишь тем цветом, который изображён картинке

Tags: photoshop

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Меняю цвет все равно итог один, к примеру у меня красный занавес, и если я хочу допустим что нибудь кистью жёлтого цвета, то у меня все равно рисует красным. Думал в динамике цвета проблема, но эта функция выключена. Может я не на тех слоях это делаю? Но, на всех кроме фонового рисует красным. Совместить не могу так как далее буду задания, а при их выполнении получится не то, что нужно.[image: -1-1-]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему кисть не рисует выбранным цветом?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1245475/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc)

Answer (score 0):

посмотрите в каком режиме вы рисуете (это сверху около меню)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и удостоверьтесь, что Normal

ну и вообще бы вы все окно показали, чтобы увидеть и другие настройки

и еще - вы в RGB пространстве рисуете? (Menu -> Image -> Mode)

Comment: Разобрались. Участник задал дубликат, но там было достаточно информаии, чтобы дать правильный ответ.