# Почему кисть не рисует выбранным цветом?

Tags: photoshop

Кисть рисует на рисунке тем цветом каким изображен рисунок, но не тем который я выбрал. В чем проблема не могу понять. Кисть создавал сам. Динамика цвета выкл.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по слоям, они у вас все в оттенках серого, и "раскрашиваются" наложением эффектов цвета. **Рисуйте в новом слое**.